# Rock paper scissors game with a window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a Rock, paper, scissors game for a school assignment, But when I try to run this script the game doesn't work properly. When I click Rock for example the computer only picks the same or picks paper. But the player never wins. I don't know how to fix this, Ive been trying for hours. This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string Computer;
    string[] computer = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
    Random random = new Random();
    int RandomType;
    string PlayerPicks;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerPicks = "Rock";
        RandomType = random.Next(0, 2);
        Computer = computer[RandomType];
        Game();
    }

    private void PaperButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerPicks = "Paper";
        RandomType = random.Next(0, 2);
        Computer = computer[RandomType];
        Game();
    }

    private void ScissorsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerPicks = "Scissors";
        RandomType = random.Next(0, 2);
        Computer = computer[RandomType];
        Game();
    }

    void Game()
    {
        string message = "The winner is: ";
        string computerWins = "Computer!";
        string playerWins = "Player!";
        string draw = "N-Nobody?";


        if (PlayerPicks == "Rock" && Computer == "Paper") // Player: Rock, Computer: paper = computer wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + computerWins);
        }
        else if (PlayerPicks == "Rock" && Computer == "Scissors") // Player: Rock, Computer: Scissors = Player wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + playerWins);

        }
        else if (PlayerPicks == "Paper" && Computer == "Scissors") // Player: Paper, Computer: Scissors = Computer wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + computerWins);

        }
        else if (PlayerPicks == "Paper" && Computer == "Rock") // Player: Paper, Computer: Rock = Player wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + playerWins);

        }
        else if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Rock") // Player: Scissors, Computer: Rock = Computer wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + computerWins);

        }
        else if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Paper") // Player: Scissors, Computer: Paper = Player wins
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + playerWins);

        }
        if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Scissor")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + draw);

        }
        if (PlayerPicks == "Paper" && Computer == "Paper")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + draw);
        }
        if (PlayerPicks == "Rock" && Computer == "Rock")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message + draw);
        }
```

Comment: btw, it should be random.Next(0,3). maxValue is exclusive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: Your draw comparison could be optimize by checking once if both values are the same like so : `if (PlayerPicks == Computer)`

Comment: By the way: you say _"only picks the same or picks paper"_.  That would correspond to 0 or 1 as the result of `Random.Next`.  That would be a good hint to test Random.Next hard.  And, once you find that it never returns a 2, you'd have a good hint that you should read the documentation

Comment: The other thing you should look at is the `enum` type.  You could have an enum that represents the three choices (then the compiler would check the spelling for you, and they convert nicely to strings).  You could also have a three state enum (PlayerWins, ComputerWins, Draw, or something like that) and a function that evaluates the two picks and determines a winner.  If you do it right, the rules for winning would be pretty simple (using standard comparison operators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1

`RandomType = random.Next(0, 2)` only generates a number between 0 and 1, you would need to do `RandomType = random.Next(0, 3)` This will generate a number between 0 and 2

Problem 2

`if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Scissor")` checks if computer picked `Scissor` instead of `Scissors` Just change this to `if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Scissors")`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach.  It has been greatly refactored from your code.  First I added a private `System.Random` member field to the form class:

```
private Random _rand = new Random();
```

Then, I set up two `enum`s, one for the "hand sign" (rock, paper, scissors) and the other for the result:

```
public enum HandSign
{
    Rock,           // rock beats scissors
    Paper,          // paper beats rock
    Scissors,       // scissors beats paper
}

public enum Result
{
    Draw,
    ComputerWins,
    PlayerWins
}
```

Then I create some helper functions, the first to determine the computer's next move:

```
private HandSign GetRandomPlay()
{
    var result = _rand.Next(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(HandSign)).Length);
    return (HandSign) result;
}
```

and the next one, the rules engine to determine the winner:

```
private Result DetermineWinner(HandSign player, HandSign computer)
{
    if (player == computer)
    {
        return Result.Draw;
    }

    if (player == HandSign.Scissors && computer == HandSign.Rock)
    {
        return Result.ComputerWins;
    }

    if (player == HandSign.Rock && computer == HandSign.Scissors)
    {
        return Result.PlayerWins;
    }

    if (player > computer)
    {
        return Result.PlayerWins;
    }

    //finally, otherwise
    return Result.ComputerWins;
}
```

Finally, one to "play the game", showing the results of the play in a handful of labels on the form:

```
 private void PlayGame(HandSign playerPicks)
 {
     PlayerPicksLbl.Text = playerPicks.ToString();
     var computerPicks = GetRandomPlay();
     ComputerPicksLbl.Text = computerPicks.ToString();
     WinnerLbl.Text = DetermineWinner(playerPicks, computerPicks).ToString();
 }
```

At that point, my three button click handlers simply look like this (this is the Rock handler):

```
 private void RockBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     PlayGame(HandSign.Rock);
 }
```

One result of structuring things this way, is that to extend this to "Rocks, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock", all you'd need to do is add two more entries to the `HandSign` enum, add a bit more logic to `DetermineWinner` and two more buttons/button handlers.

Also note that there's no way to spell "Scissors" wrong and still have this compile!

**Note:**
A Console app version of this can be found in my answer to this: [rock, paper, scissors gone wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76799304/rock-paper-scissors-gone-wrong/76807699#76807699)

Answer (score 2):

On Random.Next the upper bound is exclusive so you should do
`RandomType = random.Next(0, 3);`

In addition in:

`if (PlayerPicks == "Scissors" && Computer == "Scissor")` you have "Scissor" instead of "Scissor**s**"

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use random.Next(0,3) (as Anu Viswan mentioned in the comment)
Furthermore you have a typo at the third "if" from below where you typed *Scissor* instead of *Scissors*. I would suggest to use variables for those strings - then you don't have problems with typos.