# How do I validate a user input with int.TryParse to ensure the user entered an integer but also ensure the number was between 1 and 4

Tags: c#

I found a really good while loop that validates a user input to ensure its an integer and if not it keeps requesting the user to enter a valid integer.

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid numerical value!");
    Console.WriteLine("Select any one:\n1->ROCK\n2->PAPER\n3->SCISSOR\n4->Exit Game");
}
```

However I want to amend this so that I can also validate that the number entered by the user was between 1 and 4.

I tried this but it doesn't work, do you have any ideas of something similar?

```
while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))&& (userInput > 0 && userInput < 5))
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid numerical value!");
    Console.WriteLine("Select any one:\n1->ROCK\n2->PAPER\n3->SCISSOR\n4->Exit Game");
}
```

Comment: E.g., `while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput)) || userInput < 1 || userInput > 4) { // bad input }`

Comment: A different take on rock paper scissors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window/53750805#53750805 (my answer)

Comment: Use 'do-while' loop so that code will execute at least one time. The code which you have written demands user input even before you show him options. Conditions, you have written, are correct

Comment: @ShreekeshMurkar conditions are not correct

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. You want the loop to keep running as long as the input is *bad*, correct? So start by writing out, in plain English words, what those conditions are; then translate that formally into code.

Comment: @Shreekesh i don't know if c# supports Schrodinger's numbers yet 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your slight syntax error with the parentheses, let's go over your condition

```
while((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))&& (userInput > 0 && userInput < 5)
```

"While not a successful parse and input is greater than 0 and input is less than 5, ask for input"

Does it sound right?

If the user input is not parsed, then the parse result is actually 0. This means as soon as the user enters garbage, the loop quits (because the `!TryParse` is true so C# moves on to the next condition which is 0, 0 is not greater than 0 so the whole && is false) , which is the opposite of what it used to do (keep asking upon garbage). Further more, if they don't enter garbage and do provide a value that you ask for, like 3, because 3 is greater than 0 and less than 5, they will be asked to enter another number.

How about this for a logic instead:

"While the parse failed OR the input was less than 1 OR the input was more than 4, ask again"

Remember that && and || stop early if they encounter a false/true respectively. If the parse passes, it gets flipped to a false by the `!`, so if you're using OR, C# moves on to checking the next, trying to find a true. If your parse didn't pass, the OR will stop at the first check because it found the true it was wanting

Now, have a go at implementing it..