# How do I assign an int to a user entered string?

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables, methods

I'm an extreme beginner, only a few days into learning, so sorry if this is an obvious question.

I'm trying to use `ReadLine()` to get the user to enter a string (Rock, Paper or Scissors), then use an if statement to assign a variable of the same names a number 1-3 and then return to break out of the statement and then write the value in `Main()`. I've done the first one here b/c no point doing the rest (again) if it doesn't work for one.

The error messages from VS Code are

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'choice' of 'RockPaperScissors.Method()'

and

> Not all code paths return a value

What am I forgetting/misunderstanding?

```
using System;

class RockPaperScissors
{
    static int Method()
    {
        string playerString = Console.ReadLine();
        int rock = 1;

        if (playerString == "Rock")
        {
            int choice = rock;
            return choice;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int Move = Method();
        Console.WriteLine(Move);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is because your `Method()` method will return `choice` if `playerString == "Rock"`, but otherwise, (i.e., on another path through your code) it doesn't return anything.  Since you said it will return an `int`, you get the compilation error.  Take a look at my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window for a way to do this with `enums` (which have both a string identity and a numeric identity (kinda-sorta)).

Comment: The method `Method` *must* return an integer, because that is how you've defined it. If the input from the user is `Rock` it will return 1 - but you haven't told it what to do if the input is anything other than rock (like `Paper` or `hello` or `bob`). Hint: read up on [if...else...](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-if-else) statements...

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the error, your code handle only one use case, and it didn't return an integer for the rest of cases.
This may help:

```
        static int Method()
        {
            var playerString = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (playerString)
            {
                case "Rock":
                    return 1;
                case "Paper":
                    return 2;
                case "Scissors":
                    return 3;
                default:
                    // when the input data is not one of the previous strings 
                    // it throws an exception so it should be catched and handled  
                    throw new Exception("Not valid input");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @BreadShirt additionally, be aware, that comparison is case sensitive, so "Rock" is not "rock" is not "ROCK", etc. think about using playerString.ToLower() and comparing the result with "rock", "paper" "scissors", if that fits your requirements.

Comment: Ah, I started off using a switch but I made an instinctual assumption they it had to be case <number> b/c every example I had seen was that, whoops. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Or, making the code easier to read by using an `enum`:

```
public enum HandSign
{
    Rock,           // rock beats scissors
    Paper,          // paper beats rock
    Scissors,       // scissors beats paper
}
```

Which allows this:

```
public static HandSign GetUserChoice()
{
    HandSign result = default;
    bool isCorrectEntry = false;
    while (!isCorrectEntry)
    {
        Console.Write(@"Enter choice (Rock/Paper/Scissors): ");
        var enteredText = Console.ReadLine();
        isCorrectEntry = Enum.TryParse<HandSign>(enteredText, ignoreCase:true, out result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Notice that it will prompt you over and over again until you spell `scissors` correctly.  It also ignores the case of the entered text.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to go over enums tomorrow but wanted to test what I had already learned but thanks! I'll look back on this tomorrow!

Answer (score -2):

```
static int Method()
{
    string playerString = Console.ReadLine();
    int rock = 1;

    if (playerString == "Rock")
    {
        int choice = rock;
        return choice;
    }
     return rock;
}
```

Comment: Solves the error. They're not going to learn anything if you do if for them.