# I need help making this rock paper scissors random

Tags: c#

** I have already written out what would happen if computer said rock paper or scissors. does anyone know how to make this random? I enjoy coding and want to understand how to do it so please don't just send code if you are good at coding please explain it.**

```
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Hello! I am Computer who are you? ");
        Console.Write(" Enter name here: ");

        string Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(" Hello " + Name + " Its nice to meet you! ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(" Lets play rock paper scisors ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write(" Rock... Paper... Scisors... SHOOT! Enter 1,2 or 3: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        string UserChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        int userPoints = 0;
        int computerPoints = 0;
        //this is if coputer chose rock
        if (UserChoice == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("It is a tie.");
        }

        else if (UserChoice == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("User wins");
            userPoints++;
        }

        else if (UserChoice == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer wins");
            computerPoints++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"User has {userPoints} points - Computer has {computerPoints} points");
        // this is if computer chose paper
        if (UserChoice == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer wins");
            computerPoints++;


            Console.Read();
        }

        else if (UserChoice == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("It is a tie.");

        }

        else if (UserChoice == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("User wins");
            userPoints++;

        }

        Console.WriteLine($"User has {userPoints} points - Computer has {computerPoints} points");

        //this is if computer chose scissors
        
        if (UserChoice == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Rock");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("User wins");
            userPoints++;

        }

        else if (UserChoice == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Paper");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer wins");
            computerPoints++;


        }


        else if (UserChoice == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("It is a tie.");


        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"User has {userPoints} points - Computer has {computerPoints} points");



    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window. It uses Windows Forms, but it would be easy to translate to a console app. The computer makes its choices at random. The structure of the app simplifies its modification (in your case, to make it a console app)

Answer (score 1):

So what will be helpful for you here is the [Random class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0). In this instance, you'd want it to give output between 1-3. You'll need to create a Random object and then call the function nextInt. The parameters are the range of random numbers, with the first being inclusive and the second being exclusive (meaning the line below will give random numbers between 1 and 3).

```
var rand = new Random();
int compChoice = rand.Next(1,4);
```

This answers your question, just be aware you're taking input as a string i.e. "1", but it will probably be best practice to try parsing it into an integer.

```
var userChoiceNum = Int32.Parse(UserChoice);
```

I'd also suggest extracting some of the game logic into a separate function, which you can then call in main.

```
private function doMatch() 
{ 
    /* game logic here */ 
}
```

Comment: The method is called [Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_), not `nextInt`.

Comment: @Klaus, thanks, I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for answering I think I understand now!