# Making a rock paper scissor game c#

Tags: c#

I'm making a rock paper scissors game vs a cpu. I press a button for either rock, paper, or scissors and check with the cpu after a timer ends if it has the same picture.

My problem is nothing happens. I just see the two images. Here is the code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    label1.Text = seconds--.ToString();
    if (label1.Text == "-1")
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        Random r = new Random();
        pictureBox2.Image = picture[r.Next(picture.Length)];
        if (pictureBox1.Image == pictureBox2.Image)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Draw!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!! ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock && pictureBox2.Image == WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label1.Text = "a";
        }

        timer1.Stop();    

    }    
}
```

The `Label1.Text="a";` is just to verify the code enters the `if` block. However, it doesn't enter the block in any case and I don't know why.
here is how i assign picturebox1 for ex if i press the rock button this is what happen :

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper;
        }
```

for the second i just put it  in the form_load : int second =3;
How can I fix this?

Comment: Nothing happens because `Label1.Text` is not `-1`, possibly because the `--` operator doesn't change the value until **after** the current line.  So if you have `seconds` start at `0`, it calls `0.ToString()` for the assignment first and then changes the value to `-1` afterwards. But also, that's weird condition for the if block at all.

Comment: [Navigate through code by using Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Does the program ever enter the `timer1_Tick` handler? What is the value of `seconds` when that happens?

Comment: `seconds` is not defined in your example, and yet the whole behaviour of the example hinges on what the value of `seconds` is.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: im new its quite hard for me

Comment: You should show how you assign an image to the pictureBox1 and pictureBox2.  If the images were loaded separately they will have different references and comparing them with == will not do what you want.  You should also show how you assign `seconds` a value, and as a courtesy, you should show what the value actually is (you can read it off the label1 in your UI and tell us.)

Comment: i added what u told me

Comment: idk how to check the value

Comment: Check out my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window.  It's a full WinForms rock paper scissors game

Comment: If you put `int second = 3` in `Form_Load` then it would be a _local variable_ different from the field `seconds` that you may possibly have in your form.  `second` and `seconds` are different.   Even if you have a field called `seconds` and in your `Form_Load` you did `int seconds = 3` that would still be a local variable that __hides__ your field called `seconds`.  It's probably better to show the actual code because the littlest details can matter a lot.

Comment: You should give your elements proper names. The defaults like "Label1" and "timer1" are vague and confusing. Working cleanly from the start saves many headaches later on

Answer (score 4):

I see a big problem derived of the use of GUI to work with your data. I think is better if you work with a concrete model and update the GUI based in your model.

Here you define each player options:

```
public enum Hand
{
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissors
}
```

And the result of the game:

```
public enum GameResult
{
    Player1,
    Draw,
    Player2
}
```

You can get a random value for any player, your player or CPU player. Or you can use only for CPU player and manage your player in other way:

```
private static Hand GetRandomHand()
{
    var r = new Random();
    return (Hand)r.Next(2);
}
```

Add a method to check the winner:

```
private static GameResult CheckWinner(Hand hand1, Hand hand2)
{
    if (hand1 == hand2)
    {
        return GameResult.Draw;
    }

    switch (hand1)
    {
        case Hand.Rock:
            return hand2 == Hand.Paper ? GameResult.Player2 : GameResult.Player1;
        case Hand.Paper:
            return hand2 == Hand.Scissors ? GameResult.Player2 : GameResult.Player1;
        default: //case Hand.Scissors:
            return hand2 == Hand.Rock ? GameResult.Player2 : GameResult.Player1;
    }
}
```

Now, you can manage some things about GUI. For example, get the image of any hand options:

```
private Image GetImage(Hand hand)
{
    switch (hand)
    {
        case Hand.Rock:
            return WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.rock;
        case Hand.Paper:
            return WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper;
        default: //case Hand.Scissors:
            return WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.scissors;
    }
}
```

Add two fields in your form (player1 for you and player2 for CPU, for example):

```
private Hand player1Hand = GetRandomHand();
private Hand player2Hand = GetRandomHand();
```

With all the previous code, that is very simple, now it's easy manage everything about the game:

```
// Get a random value for each player. You can choose in other form a value for your player 
// and use the random only for CPU player
this.player1Hand = GetRandomHand();
this.player2Hand = GetRandomHand();

// Set the appropiate image
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(this.player1Hand);
pictureBox2.Image = GetImage(this.player2Hand);

// Check the result
var result = CheckWinner(this.player1Hand, this.player2Hand);
switch (result)
{
    case GameResult.Player1:
        MessageBox.Show("You win!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        break;
            
    case GameResult.Draw:
        MessageBox.Show("Draw!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        break;
            
    case GameResult.Player2:
        MessageBox.Show("Cpu Wins!!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        break;
}
```

To set a value for `player1Hand`, you can use the `Hand` enum values:

```
player1Hand = Hand.rock;
```

After set this value (from a dropdown, radio button...) you can update the player1 image:

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(this.player1Hand);
```

Comment: thank u for this i just tried to assign a pic in player1 cz im choosing  
                private Hand player1Hand =  (Bitmap) WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.paper;
but i got an error :
  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Hand'

Comment: player1Hand is an enum type, not an Image. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Altough this is not a performance critical application, you don't need a new Random object every method call. You could have one static instance

Comment: @JHBonarius you are right. I tried avoid complicate things but he can work with only a one Random instance as you said. Maybe interesting also create a game class but I prefer don't complicate my answer because Rami knowledge appear basic.

Comment: Upvote.  To the person who wrote the question... subtly one thing Victor is doing here is SEPARATING business logic from UI concerns.  I know you're probably a new (original question asker).......but this is important to try to learn from the get-go.  internet serach : https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+layers&oq=c%23+layers&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i433i512j0i131i433i512l3j69i58.2771j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8