# rock, paper, scissors gone wrong

Tags: c#, random

I'm a beginner in c#, I was making a simple rock, paper, scissors game, when the code was done I ran it, and the problem is that each time I pick rock, paper or scissors I get stuck in a loop where the console displays the computer pick, and if I won or lost (or if it's a tie).

here is a look at my stuckable, unsuccesful code :

```
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Random random = new Random();

bool playagain = true;
String player = "";
int computer;
computer = random.Next(1,4);
Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
player = Console.ReadLine();
player = player.ToUpper();

while (playagain == true)
{
    
    
    while (player != "ROCK" && player != "PAPER" && player != "SCISSORS")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
        player = Console.ReadLine();
        player.ToUpper();


    }



    switch (computer)
    {
        case 1:// computer = rock
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : Rock");
                Console.WriteLine("It's a tie !");
            }


            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Computer : ROCK");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose !");


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");

            }
            break;
        case 2:// computer = paper
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose !");
            }


            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("It's  a tie  !");


            }
            else// player = scissors 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : PAPER");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");

            }

            break;
        case 3: // computer = scissors 
            if (player.Equals("ROCK"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You win !");
            }


            else if (player.Equals("PAPER"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose  !");


            }
            else// player = scissors 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer : SCISSORS");
                Console.WriteLine("It's a tie  !");

            }
            break;

            

    }


    }
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
    String response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    playagain = response == "yes";
    if (playagain.Equals("yes"))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
        player = Console.ReadLine();



        }
```

can anyone solve this, it's prolly an easy fix, but i'm to new to figure it out....

i tried moving the part where the player is asked if he want to continue tha game or not, specifcally this portion of the code :

```
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
    String response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    playagain = response == "yes";
    if (playagain.Equals("yes"))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
        player = Console.ReadLine();



        }
```

nothing changed.

Comment: *"when the code was done i ran it"* - You're going to stuggle if you write code this way. Write small bits, test, repeat. Read [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You use `player = player.ToUpper();` to make the string uppercase before the loop but use it improperly in the error condition and not at all if they choose to play again. You need to be consistent.

Comment: Fix the indentation of the code. Then you will see what is in the loop and what comes after the loop. Maybe you should place some code preceding the loop inside the loop?

Comment: Another hint: if you expect the user to write whole words for choices, expect spelling mistakes. Maybe just take the first chars (r,p,s) or number code the choices.

Comment: You would also benefit greatly by taking some time to learn how to use the debugger to step through your code. You'll be able to easily see where things happen that you did not expect and correct them.

Comment: And it's not a problem _here_ but should you ever need to test equality of strings regardless case, prefer a case-insensitive equality operation. ToUpper or ToLower won't always work, especially if you need to go international (looking at you,  turqish "i" ...).

Comment: Take a look at the code in my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window/53750805#53750805). It may give you some ideas

Comment: Oh, and if you use my code, you won't be don't string comparisons. Instead, use `enum.TryParse<TEnum>` (the overload with the bool to indicate that you want a case-insensitive parse) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-enum-tryparse-1(system-string-system-boolean-0@)

Comment: I gave very simple solution in your earlier posting : When you loose (or win) set playagain = false to you exit the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

I am new as well to coding so I tried to solve your issue. There are some main things that you need to adress and I just know what I thought was the issue and how I would like to fix them, these are probably not optimal but will help you on your way to a better code.

Problems:

1. If the boolean is not being set to false, the code will continue to loop and that is your main issue.
2. Your second while-loop only gets "activated" and let the user enter the ROCK/PAPER/SCISSORS if the string 'player' isn't ROCK/PAPER/SCISSORS already. Thus on the second re-run the user won't be given a chance to enter a new ROCK/PAPER/SCISSORS.
3. The third issue is that you have the computers random number stated outside of the loops and therefor the computer will always have the same ROCK/PAPER/SCISSORS vs you as long as you don't stop the simulation and re-run it.

Answers:

1. I put the "check if player wants to play again part" into the first while-loop and I changed the code to the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
String response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
if (response.Equals("!yes"))
{
    playagain = false;
}
```

2. I changed your while-loop to a do-while-loop, the difference is that a do-while-loop always loops at least once and checks the loop condition after the loop. This allows the user to give a new ROCK/PAPER/SCISSORS. See example below:

```
while (playagain == true)

    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter, ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS : ");
            player = Console.ReadLine();
            player.ToUpper();
        } while (player != "ROCK" && player != "PAPER" && player != "SCISSORS");
```

3. I believe you can handle this error if you would like to by entering the new random number into the loop somewhere, not sure but I don't have the time to try it out.

And I think the pointers the others given before me is really good. Debugging is something I need to learn as well, if we know how to debug we will be able to solve our issues more independently and thus making us better coders.

Best of luck to you and see you around on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code a bit, more than you explained, and I also tried debugging which worked well, now the code is running like a charm.

Comment: `player.ToUpper();` does not modify the string in place. It returns a new uppercase string. If you are not capturing that return value then that line does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely generic version (i.e., it's easily adaptable to "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock") that does almost no string comparison.

First, I define an enumerated type for the choices:

```
public enum HandSign
{
    Rock,           // rock beats scissors
    Paper,          // paper beats rock
    Scissors,       // scissors beats paper
}
```

By using an enumerated type, I don't need to worry about strings for these choices.

Then I create another that determines who won:

```
public enum Result
{
    Draw,
    ComputerWins,
    PlayerWins
}
```

Most of the code lives in a `Game` class.  The first thing that goes in the class is a random number generator that I'll be using for the computer generated choices:

```
public class Game
{
    private Random _rand = new Random();
}
```

I'll be adding code to that class for most of the rest of this exercise.

I need a *Rules Engine* that decides who wins.  I can take advantage of the fact that an enumerated type is ordered and comparable:

```
public Result DetermineWinner(HandSign player, HandSign computer)
{
    if (player == computer)
    {
        return Result.Draw;
    }

    if (player == HandSign.Scissors && computer == HandSign.Rock)
    {
        return Result.ComputerWins;
    }

    if (player == HandSign.Rock && computer == HandSign.Scissors)
    {
        return Result.PlayerWins;
    }

    if (player > computer)
    {
        return Result.PlayerWins;
    }

    //finally, otherwise
    return Result.ComputerWins;
}
```

Note that, with the two enumerated types, it is pretty much self-documenting

I wanted to make it so that you could substitute another Enumerated type for a different set of options (like "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock").  So much of this code is written in terms of a generic `TEnum` type `where TEnum: struct, Enum`.  This means that you can pass the type of the Handsign to most of these methods.

The first is the small function that generates the computer moves:

```
private TEnum GetRandomPlay<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    var result = _rand.Next(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Length);
    // there's no easy/straightforward way to convert an int to a generic Enum, 
    // but this works:
    return (TEnum) Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), result);
}
```

The last piece of the `Game` class is the *Game Engine* that prompts the user and runs the game.  The argument to this method is a delegate to function that takes two arguments (each a `HandSign` in this case, but in the generic case, any Enum) and returns a `Result` - i.e., the *Rules Engine*.

It will run forever until the user enters a `"Q"` to quit:

```
public void PlayTillQuit<TEnum>(Func<TEnum, TEnum, Result> whoWinsMethod) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    var choices = Enum.GetNames<TEnum>();       //retrieves choices as an array of strings
    var prompt = string.Join(", ", choices);    //combines them into a single string separated by commas and spaces

    // runs forever until user types "Q" <enter>
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter one of {prompt} <Q to quit>: ");
        var entered = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.Equals("Q", entered, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        // tries to convert entered string to one of the enum choices
        if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(entered, true, out var playerChoice))
        {
            var computerChoice = GetRandomPlay<TEnum>();
            var result = whoWinsMethod(playerChoice, computerChoice);
            Console.WriteLine($"You chose: {playerChoice} - Computer chose: {computerChoice} - Result: {result}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the lack of string comparison (except for the `"Q"` to quit (and it uses an ignore-case comparison)).  Also note that the only place in the code that `Rock`, `Paper` or `Scissors` exist is in the definition of the `HandSign` enumerated type.  You don't have to worry about spelling `Scissors` inconsistently in your code.

The user entered choices are parsed using the ignore-case version of `Enum.TryParse`.  As long as the entered string is a valid `TEnum` (in this case, a valid `HandSign`), it will return true.  It will return false if it's not.

At this point, all that's left is the Main program.  It simply instantiates a game object and runs it, calling the `PlayTillQuit` *Game Engine* and passing in the `DetermineWinner` *Rules Engine*"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rock - Paper - Scissors");
    Console.WriteLine();
    var game = new Game();
    game.PlayTillQuit<HandSign>(game.DetermineWinner);
}
```

Here's what running the program produces:

```
Rock - Paper - Scissors

Enter one of Rock, Paper, Scissors <Q to quit>:
rock
You chose: Rock - Computer chose: Scissors - Result: PlayerWins

Enter one of Rock, Paper, Scissors <Q to quit>:
PAPER
You chose: Paper - Computer chose: Rock - Result: PlayerWins

Enter one of Rock, Paper, Scissors <Q to quit>:
Bad
Error!
Enter one of Rock, Paper, Scissors <Q to quit>:
Scissors
You chose: Scissors - Computer chose: Rock - Result: ComputerWins

Enter one of Rock, Paper, Scissors <Q to quit>:
q
```

If you want, you could extend this to keep score (with variables local to the `PlayTillQuit` *Game Engine*)

Finally, if you want to adapt this to "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock", just create a different Enum for the hand signs, and make the `whoWinsMethod` parameter (aka `DetermineWinner`) a tad more complex.

**Note:**
A Windows Forms version of this can be found in my answer here: [Rock paper scissors game with a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746727/rock-paper-scissors-game-with-a-window/53750805#53750805)